# Is it possible to install KVM in WSL 1?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-kvm, wsl2

I have WSL 1 installed on my Windows 10 machine in which Ubuntu 20.04 is installed. My CPU supports hardware virtualization. I followed instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) to try to install KVM, but when I run "virsh list --all", I got

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

The output of `kvm-ok` is

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: FATAL: Module msr not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
```

So, is it because WSL 1 can't install KVM? kvm is ok only on WSL 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. KVM is a Linux kernel feature, and WSL1 doesn't have a Linux kernel; it *imitates* a Linux kernel, somewhat like Wine imitating the Windows environment. You cannot actually load Linux `.ko` modules into it.

This *may* be possible in WSL2 – in theory – as WSL2 runs a real Linux kernel and does so through Hyper-V, which supports "[nested virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization)" if the CPU is also compatible, meaning that the WSL2 VM could itself run more VMs inside. However, I don't know if the standard Microsoft-provided Linux kernel <sub>(words you never thought you'd hear)</sub> is compiled with KVM support, but at least they have instructions for compiling a custom kernel.

It might *also* be possible to somehow convince your libvirtd to run Qemu *on Windows,* as Qemu actually supports running VMs through the Windows Hypervisor Platform (which is the Windows equivalent of KVM), so you could run WSL2 and `qemu.exe -accel whpx` side-by-side without them conflicting.

(Of course, Qemu on Windows can also use the Intel HAXM hypervisor with `-accel hax`.)

---

*(Perhaps WSL1 could implement the /dev/kvm API in terms of Windows Hypervisor Platform, but it doesn't do that, and I don't think it's going to receive any new features given that the focus in WSL2.)*

Comment: At least on Windows 10, there's no `/dev/kvm` in WSL 2.

Comment: I have to stick to WSL1 because I can't upgrade to newer version of Windows. But your reply inspired me: why not create a VM of newer Windows 10 and install WSL2 in it? There is an article: https://boxofcables.dev/accelerated-kvm-guests-on-wsl-2/. It is on WSL2 but I tried it on WSL1 before asking this question. I compiled the kernel successfully but failed at copying bzImage because there is no such folder. I'll try it again in the WSL2 in guest Windows. Thank you for your answer that enlivens my life.

Comment: @Daniel B: This article made it (see its screenshot): https://boxofcables.dev/accelerated-kvm-guests-on-wsl-2/

Comment: @zzzhhh - Then what you want cannot be accomplished without WSL2 support